# Difference in pronunciation of a word in 4:163 (surat an-Nisa)

Tags: quran-recitation, reading-quran

I was reading the Qur'an and came to the following ayat :

[Surat an-Nisa 4:163](http://quran.com/4/163)

إِنَّا أَوْحَيْنَا إِلَيْكَ كَمَا أَوْحَيْنَا إِلَىٰ نُوحٍ وَالنَّبِيِّينَ مِن بَعْدِهِ ۚ وَأَوْحَيْنَا إِلَىٰ إِبْرَاهِيمَ وَإِسْمَاعِيلَ وَإِسْحَاقَ وَيَعْقُوبَ وَالْأَسْبَاطِ وَعِيسَىٰ وَأَيُّوبَ وَيُونُسَ وَهَارُونَ وَسُلَيْمَانَ ۚ وَآتَيْنَا دَاوُودَ زَبُورًا

The words "Noah and the" are what caught my attention. Here the transliteration becomes :

noohin wannabiyyeenamin.

I compared this with a different Qur'an, and there the transliteration became

noohiyo wannabiyyeenamin.

Meaning there was a tashahhud over the letter و, connecting the words together.

Is this simply a matter of different ways of recitation that are allowed ?

**Edit:**
I just listened to a recitation by Muhammad Siddiq al-Minshawi and he used the latter style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a mix of two things:
**A transliteration of an Arabic text:** as there are no fixed rules or at least those people whom transliterate don't use the exact rule or at least don't explain wich of the common rules they use. (See for example [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3AManual_of_Style/Arabic) proposed in our [meta site](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/transliteration-protocol) and this [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Arabic)).

**Rules of tajweed:** as the rules of tajweed let the text sound a better. This is which is translated as measured recitation in [73:4](http://legacy.quran.com/73/4) in this case there's a "tanwyn تنوين or [nunation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nunation)" on the last letter حٍ of Nuh followed by a "Idgham ادغام or [diphthong](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/islam/home.php?word=%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%BA%D8%A7%D9%85&lang_name=ar-en&type_word=0&dspl=0)" on the letter وَ which changes the pronunciation of this letter in the recitation and therefore has an impact on a transliteration that takes this into account.

So transliteration one:
*noohin (or nuhin) wa-nnabiyyeena min* - 
 is a transliteration that doesn't take into account how this verse should be recited. It is using only the classical way the text would be read in any Arabic text book!

While transliteration two:
*noohiyo wa-nnabiyyeena-min* - IMO is only a try to show the applied tajweed or tarteel rule. Maybe *"noohii-wa ..."* is more correct.

That's why this transliteration would be closer to how the verse is recited or performed by a reciter.